# How to scroll bottom and click the button using karate-appium?

Tags: appium, karate

I have a button named just the symbol ">". I want to click the button to move next window. I tried the following code, but it's not working.

[image]

```
     And driver.script("mobile: scroll", { "strategy" : "accessibility id", "selector": ">" })
     And driver.optional('@>').click()
```

stopped in this line `And driver.script("mobile: scroll", { "strategy" : "accessibility id", "selector": ">" })`.
need help. @peter_thomas, @babu_sekaran, or someone